# transform the basis vectors into an orthonormal basis.

Tags: inner-products, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

Let 3 have the Euclidean inner product. Use Gram-Schmidt process to transform the basis vectors 1=(1,0,0),2=(3,7,−2),3=(0,4,1) into an orthonormal basis

I was able to find alpha1=(1/√2,0,0) but got lost after that can someone please help me out
I have attached the picture of the solution where i think i am making a mistake

[image]

Comment: Are you that sure $|(1,0,0)|=\sqrt{1^2+0^2+0^2}=\sqrt{\color{red}2}$?

Comment: Type your solution please.

Comment: that is √2 please don't judge me by my handwriting

Comment: Definetely. Should be $\sqrt{1}$. No one does judge you by handwriting (mine is no better, so I use MathJax -- pictures aren't searchable).

Comment: shit man lol thanks a lot

Comment: I feel so stupid

Comment: I didn't check any further

Comment: okay so i corrected that mistake and re-uploaded my answer can you please verify